# What is the meaning of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

This is used in many posts related to functions and googling it doesn't help.
What does this mean? $\mathbb{R}$ should stand for all Real numbers.

Comment: The latex command for $\setminus$ is *setminus*. That says it.

Comment: The set of nonzero reals.

Comment: Another example of how the zeal for symbols over natural language words obscures rather than elucidates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Real numbers that aren't $0$. \ is set difference.

Comment: R-{0} is the same thing as this then?

Comment: @user1848858 yes

Comment: Thank you for your quick help.

Answer (score 5):

This refers to the set $\mathbb{R}$ , but without $0$, i.e. the complement of $\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I do not think "complement" is the word you seek.

Comment: the complement of?

Comment: @user1848858 Relative complement of $\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the set of all elements in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\{0\}$.